# Vim: "." in cword

Tags: vim

I'm in Vim.

I want [<cword>](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Ccword%3E) to consider "." are a character that is part of a word (rather than a character that separates words). How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to the `iskeyword` option. For example,

```
:set iskeyword?
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
:set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
```

Comment: No need to get the previous value: `:set iskeyword+=.` Also, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4011/2598.